# Probabililty of sums of gaussians

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X\sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2)$. Consider an arbitrary $r\in\mathbb{R}$. How can I compute the probability of $\mathbb{P}(X \leq r \leq X + Y)$?

My idea: One could write the probability as $$\int_{-\infty}^r \phi_{(\mu_1, \sigma_1)}(x) \cdot(1-\Phi_{(\mu_2, \sigma_2)}(r-x)) \; dx,$$ where $\Phi_{(\mu, \sigma)}$ denotes the CDF and $\phi_{(\mu, \sigma)}$ the PDF of $N(\mu, \sigma)$. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think but i am not sure that you can write :
$\mathbb{P}(X\leq r\leq X+Y)=\mathbb{E}(1_{\{X\leq r\leq X+Y\}})=\int_{E}g(x,y)d\mathbb{P}_{(X,X+Y)}$ via transfer formula where $g(x,y)=1_{\{x\leq r\leq x+y\}}$**To be checked!**

that means you need to find the density of the couple $(X,X+Y)$ **To be checked also !**.

I didn't say here it's a better way but it may help !

Comment: The formula that you wrote is interesting also !

Comment: Interesting, thanks! But X+Y don't have to be independent even though X and Y are independent.

Comment: Yes true sorry for the mistake , the right result is if $X$ and $Y$ are independants so are $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ for every measurable functions g and f